# I can't run MySQL service [Attempting to start MySQL service...] (XAMPP)

Tags: mariadb, xampp

I have problems with xampp control panel, I try to start the mysql process but when I click start I get a "network command" window to enable permissions, I click ok and all I get is a message [mysql ] Trying to start the MySQL service... I have searched for information on the internet and consulted in forums but I have not obtained information about it. I've tried uninstalling and installing Xampp and checking my firewall permissions, but nothing seems to be interfering. This has stopped my progress for several days on a local project using a database. I appreciate any help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ussually if it is stuck, it may have failed. If it has failed, it will log the error on the event viewer. Check for any errors there.

Alternatively, you can try to run it via the Services snap-in. It should give a much better message there on what the issue might be.